# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, what is the name of the Default Desktop / GUI?

Tags: 18.04, gui, desktop-environments

For Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
*what is the name of the Default Desktop / GUI*?
For the Default install of Ubuntu.
Is it Unity OR GNOME? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It's [GNOME](https://www.gnome.org/), you can see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/index.html).

Ubuntu used to have home-grown Unity as the default, but they switched to GNOME since version 17.10 (announced [here](https://ubuntu.com/blog/growing-ubuntu-for-cloud-and-iot-rather-than-phone-and-convergence) by [Mark Shuttleworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Shuttleworth)).